# can i enable jwplayer video quality option selector on mobile phones

Tags: jwplayer

I'm using jwplayer to play videos with quality selector option(multi resolution) on my [video](https://funxnxx.com/) site and it's working fine on PC browser but in mobile phone it's hide and users can't select quality it's self.

[image: jwplayer videos quality selector option]

```
<script>
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
      image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
      sources: [{
        file: "/uploads/myVideo.m3u8"
      }]
    });
</script>
```

any one know how to enable quality selector option on mobile browser.